# Ubuntu 20.04. Attempt to delete printer from list of printers fails

Tags: lubuntu, settings

Glad to be here!

New to Lubuntu 20.04, and slowly getting this pc ready to handle my work obligations.

Just finished adding our Network printers; and now want to get rid of the "bad" printer that I initially added: However, when I select "Delete", it goes away and comes back 1 second later. Sumptin's up ...

Best steps / cmd's to correct this?

TIA MDP

Background: Lenovo X220, Netgear C7000, Dell e525W, HP M118 ... the e525W originally failed (received "error" when attempting to print); now that it's correctly installed, I want to remove the "bad" entry in the list of Printers.

Comment: I read there are 2 entries for the same printer and 1 does not work. Remove them both and then reinstall the good one.

Comment: Thanks! I'm amenable to trying anything ... But ... If I'm unable to Remove the "bad" one, I presume that indicates that I'd be unable to Remove any of the Printers ..?